# what is __type keyword in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
interface IAnotherService extends Service1<string> {
  __type: "com.east.service#anotherservice";
}
```

My question is what is the "__type" keyword? What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a keyword; it's just the name of a property in an interface, like `bar` in

```
interface Foo { 
  bar: string; 
}
```

So if you have a value `v` of type `IAnotherService`, then you can presumably index into it like `v.__type`:

```
declare const v: IAnotherService;
v.__type; // okay
```

Without more context it's hard to be sure if this is a real property (you can access it at runtime) or phantom property (it is not really there but you just use it so TypeScript can keep track of extra type information not present at runtime).  The double underscore is a hint to me that it might be the latter. One use of phantom properties is to simulate nominal typing, known as "branding" a type; see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible) for more information.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7CQRgDwAqAfMgN4CwAUMsgM6YQAUAlAFzIEDcVAvlVaEixEKAJIBBEAHswAC2jooWJMggAPSCAAmtNJmwR8tMFFABzEhWrIA+jbABPAA4R2AIgRSAtgDoIcYx96JQMAYjhpOWhg5Qg3bko+SiotCAQAGzgoFE8QY2QMdglI+ShFWISMHztHF05kAHoG5CkAazgHfkogA)